# i want to get my daily step count from google fit

Tags: android, api, kotlin, google-fit

I'm writing an android application which works with Google Fit APIs to collect daily user's step count.
I want to get my daily step count. this code return me a whole years step count.

How can I get the Google daily step Count value?

```
override fun onConnected(bundle: Bundle?) {
    val dataSourceRequest = DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
        .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
        .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
        .build()

    val dataSourcesResultCallback =
        ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult> { dataSourcesResult ->
            for (dataSource in dataSourcesResult.dataSources) {
                if (DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE == dataSource.dataType) {
                    registerFitnessDataListener(
                        dataSource,
                        DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE
                    )
                }
            }
        }

    Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(
        mApiClient,
        dataSourceRequest
    )
        .setResultCallback(dataSourcesResultCallback)
}

private fun registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource: DataSource, dataType: DataType) {
    val request = SensorRequest.Builder()
        .setDataSource(dataSource)
        .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
        .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build()
    Fitness.SensorsApi.add(mApiClient, request, this)
        .setResultCallback { status ->
            if (status.isSuccess) {
                Log.d("GoogleFit", "SensorApi successfully added")
            }
        }
}


override fun onDataPoint(dataPoint: DataPoint) {

    for (field in dataPoint.dataType.fields) {
        val value = dataPoint.getValue(field)
        runOnUiThread(Runnable {
            stepCounterTextView.setText("Field1: " + field.name + " Value1: " + value)
        })
    }
}
```

I replaced DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE with a DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA but it doesnoot work.

Comment: The registration and authantication things are ok.

Comment: Your google account comes up you select it and after that the google permission dialog appears and select yes

Answer (score 0):

Visit https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/request/SessionReadRequest
for get daily step count read